# All my java applications now throw a java.awt.headlessexception

Tags: java, swing

So a couple days ago I had several working *Java* applications using the *Swing* library, *JFrame* in particular. They all worked perfectly fine and now they all throw this exception:

```
java.awt.headlessexception
```

I don't know what changed maybe my *Java* version got updated by accident.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

EDIT:

Here's a small piece of code that gives me the exception.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class test {

  public static JFrame frame;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: A small example that throws this exception would help a lot.

Comment: This exception is thrown when code that is dependent on a keyboard, display, or mouse is called in an environment that does not support a keyboard, display, or mouse. How you're executing your app?

Comment: I'll see if I can write something small really quick that does it. All the examples are large parts of code. I'm executing it on my laptop as a Java Application. It used to work.

Comment: What OS? Are you executing from the command line or from within the context of a graphical environment?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 16 and Eclipse for Java Dev.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a headless JRE installed? (Check your Java installation, if in doubt, try reinstalling.)

Comment: I'll try that real quick.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for your insight, I tried running it from the command line and found that the _javac_ command was not even recognized haha. IDK how that happened but I reinstalled openJDK and it all works now.

Answer (score 19):

> **`HeadlessException`**
>
> Thrown when code that is dependent on a keyboard, display, or mouse is called in an environment that does not support a keyboard, display, or mouse.

To fix your issue just use

> `java -Djava.awt.headless=false`

[Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html)

Comment: You can also avoid HeadlessException with -Djava.awt.headless=false :) Thanks!

Comment: Your answer didnt work for me.  But @Xdg comment does. So you might want to take that in account. Btw I  tryed to instantiate  an object  containing JFrame field. as a Bean.

Comment: @CodeToLife ok, changed :)

Comment: Also for any standalone  app you can put this instruction: `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");` in its  context (or BeanFactory) java file

Answer (score 8):

Multiple Linux distros have separate packages for the base of the JRE vs the JRE GUI.

On RHEL7/CentOS 7 for example, if you only have this package installed:

- java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless

You also need to install this package:

- java-1.8.0-openjdk

Answer (score -1):

You can try to change a JRE you are currently using. Go to the "Run Configuration" of your project and change a JRE from your project's default to a Java Platform "standard" version.