# Java Headless exception while draw image

Tags: java, swing, drawimage, headless

I needs to modify the image (resize + add text) on the server side like this:

```
BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth() + 50, image.getHeight() + 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics graphics = tmp.getGraphics();
graphics.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), 40);
graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 40, null);
graphics.setFont(graphics.getFont().deriveFont(25f));
graphics.setColor(Color.red);
graphics.drawString(textImage, 20, 30);
graphics.dispose();
```

However, I get this error

```
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
```

Is there something that I forgot? Locally it works ok but on the Linux server gets an error as above.

Thanks for help.

EDIT: or is there workaround to avoid this headless exception?

EDIT2: OK I got logs from server:

```
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:64)
```

Someone before tried do this

```
GraphicsConfiguration config = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
BufferedImage tmp = config.createCompatibleImage(image.getWidth() + 50, image.getHeight() + 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Comment: at which row? what is textImage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All my java applications now throw a java.awt.headlessexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343529/all-my-java-applications-now-throw-a-java-awt-headlessexception)

Comment: @mauretto BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth() + 50, image.getHeight() + 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics graphics = tmp.getGraphics();

Comment: @user2363971 textImage, the line before the last. BTW Berger replied to you.

Comment: @mauretto textImage = "Centered text on image" - just String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met that error time ago while installing a war application on a Linux server with no graphical environment.

Starting the jvm with the `-Djava.awt.headless=true` should solve your problem. Please keep in mint that if your code runs within an application server you will need to modify the application server VM whith that parameter.