# I switched to Linux and now I get a java.awt.HeadlessException

Tags: java, linux, headless

I am making a 2D game engine using the core java library, and just switched to linux. Before my game engine would run fine, but now that I've switched to linux, when I try to run the code, it throws a `java.awt.HeadlessException.`

How can i fix this?

This is the class that throws the error. I'm not sure how much it's gonna help though. There's a lot more to it. I'm pretty sure the only important thing is that I use the awt library for keyevents.

```
package Platformer;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        GameComponent gp=new MainGame();
        frame.add(gp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running on a Linux *server*, or a Linux *desktop*?

Comment: have you tried to uninstall and reinstall java sdk?

Comment: @aldok What good should _that_ do? Programming is not a trial and fail game.

Comment: @Makoto And what is the difference between those?

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343529/all-my-java-applications-now-throw-a-java-awt-headlessexception

Comment: @arkascha maybe compatibility issues? If I have a good answer I wouldn't put it on comment section

Comment: @aldok If so, what sense does it make to reinstall a package? The reinstalled content will be as incompatible again, obviously. Reinstalling something may only help if an installation is somehow broken or corrupted which is very unlikely on a Linux system. There are no indications of such issue here and if there were then it certainly would first make sense to use the software managements feature to check the integrity of the installed package before unwrapping the sledge hammer...

Comment: Beside the cause Rubico mentioned it might also be caused by an undefined `DISPLAY` environment. Check by issuing `echo $DISPLAY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  exception  says  that the JRE which is  installed in that  linux machine might not contain headless JRE.

Headless JRE are the package which  provides dependencies used for the graphical components.

Check your Java installation, if in doubt, try reinstalling

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it