# getting java.awt.HeadlessException exception while executing 'maximize window function' on mac machine from from remote machine over ssh

Tags: java, macos, selenium, jenkins, ssh

**Problem Statement :** 
Whenever selenium java jar is getting called remotely over ssh , its throwing exception :java.awt.HeadlessException

Description :
I have two mac machine. On first machine I have all preset up needed for Selenium execution along with my java project. I have enabled ssh service on first machine. 
On second mac machine I have jenkins configured with job and I am trying to run sh script (which internally runs jar with all latest code changes) present on first machine 
Getting exception : java.awt.HeadlessException
I tried with different existing solutions/ options still getting this exeception 
Its specific with mac - selenium : maximize window function .

I have created below code snippet for easy verification/replication of issue to others.

**Steps to replicate issue :**

1. You should have mac machine with ssh service enabled on it.
2. Please verify it is accessible or not or other machine present in same network over ssh.
3. Please keep below java code & sh script at some location on current machine.

   **Sh script : TriggerScript.sh**

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   javac UIConfigurationUtility.java
   java UIConfigurationUtility
   ```

   **Java Class :  UIConfigurationUtility.java**

   ```
   import java.awt.Dimension;
   import java.awt.Toolkit;

   public class UIConfigurationUtility {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           UIConfigurationUtility uiConfigurationUtility = new UIConfigurationUtility();
           uiConfigurationUtility.getDimensions();
       }

       /**
        * 
        * @throws Exception
        */
       public void getDimensions() {
           try {
               //System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
               Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
               double width = dimension.getWidth();
               double height = dimension.getHeight();
               if(width >= 1280.0) {
                   if(width == 1280.0 && height < 800.0){
                       throw new Exception("Resolution settings on machine are less than required minimum configuration");
                   }
                   if(height < 768.0) {
                       throw new Exception("Resolution settings on machine are less than required minimum configuration");
                   }
               } else {
                   throw new Exception("Resolution settings on machine are less than required minimum configuration");
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               System.out.println("Resolution settings on machine are less than required minimum configuration");
           }
       }

   }
   ```
4. Please call below **TriggerScript.sh** script from remote machine :

Note : $HOME_FOLDER : is location of folder where UIConfigurationUtility.java & TriggerScript.sh is present.

e.g commands I used :

```
ssh username@remotemachine'sIP (Please put password)
cd $HOME_FOLDER
./TriggerScript.sh
```

Throwing an exception :

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getScreenSize(HeadlessToolkit.java:33)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343529/all-my-java-applications-now-throw-a-java-awt-headlessexception