# Headless exception while GUI testing (java swing) with gitlab-ci

Tags: java, swing, unit-testing, gitlab-ci, headless

I've a virtual server running a gitlab runner.
I've now added some GUI unit tests which run nicely on my pc but not on the virtual server.

It always exits with:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
```

Any idea how to get this running with gitlab-ci?

Edit:

My virtual server is running centos 7

This im my current .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: kaiwinter/docker-java8-maven
#maven:3-jdk-7

before_script:
  - "Xvfb :99 &"
  - "export DISPLAY=:99"

maven_build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - "mvn clean package"
  - "cat target/site/jacoco/index.html"
```

Now, the headlessexception is gone but basically all unit tests are failing due to awt exceptions like:
Could not initialize class java.awt.image.IndexColorModel

Edit2:
I've added the headless option as suggested:

```
image: kaiwinter/docker-java8-maven
#maven:3-jdk-7

before_script:
  - "Xvfb :99 &"
  - "export DISPLAY=:99"

maven_build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - "mvn clean package -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  - "cat target/site/jacoco/index.html"
```

Now I get the headless exceptions again...

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343529/all-my-java-applications-now-throw-a-java-awt-headlessexception

Answer (score 1):

You try using **xvfb** program like in this post http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless.

I have used xvfb to run browser from text terminal. Your case is basically the same.

The problem is that your program expects to be run in window environment, but you are running it from text terminal.

Comment: Looks like the solution. However, I cannot find the correct configuration for my gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: You can create the xvfb buffer outside travis and set the ENV variable in travis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Headless Mode:

```
  maven_build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - "mvn clean package -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

Comment: See Edit2. Did not help :-(

Comment: Read the JavaSE headless mode restrictions here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found a solution!

I've created a DOCKER image which is prepared for GUI testing (using xvfb, thanks vbuhlev):
https://github.com/thorstenwagner/docker-java8-maven

In the .gitlab-ci.yml I've added the following lines:

```
before_script:
  - "Xvfb :99 &"
  - "export DISPLAY=:99"
```

Comment: I get java.awt.HeadlessException with this. Any help?