# Springboot standalone application supports Rest & UI

Tags: spring-boot

Is there a way to develop springboot application that support the following:

1- Avail Rest API to be called from any webApp.
2- the challenge here after calling the the rest API in step#1, I need to do some stuff and then display a confirmation pop-up to the user and response to the caller with Json response.

Example:
1- webApp call Rest API so in Springboot Application I created the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(test.class, args);
}
```

2- this Rest API should do 2 things:

2.1.do some manipulation on the input provided to the rest API
2.2.Display a pop-window confirm the manipulation result by the user.
2.3.Return manipulated result to the webApp

So I created another application class as :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDesktopSampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Override
public void run(String... args) {
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Spring Boot Swing App");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JTextField text = new JTextField("Spring Boot can be used with Swing apps");
    panel.add(text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

And in the controller of the restAPI:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
public class TestController {

 @GetMapping
public void confirm() {
     new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringDesktopSampleApplication.class).headless(false).run("Data");
}
}
```

it gives

> Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException: null
> at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:165) ~[na:na]
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.(Window.java:538) ~[na:na]
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:423) ~[na:na]
> at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:224) ~[na:na]
> at com.escc.verify.application.SpringDesktopSampleApplication.run(SpringDesktopSampleApplication.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
> ... 10 common frames omitted

Any idea ?

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, your question is just too broad to answer.

Comment: @AmirSchnell I updated the question with all details

Comment: Your error doesn't have anything to do with Spring Boot, it is coming from Swing/AWT. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343529/all-my-java-applications-now-throw-a-java-awt-headlessexception

Comment: Thanks @ScottFrederick for your reply. It is working fine if it is only one springApplication defined in springboat.  But the error displayed in case i defined two "@SpringBootApplication"

Comment: `only one springApplication defined in springboat` I don't know what this means. What is springboat?